# How does auto Vacuum cleares non transaction table old transactions?

Tags: postgresql

How the Non transaction table single record update  will be vacuumed as per  auto vacuum settings it never selected single record page, but how old transaction will cleared on this table and save from wraparound.

I tried by changing all kind of settings in auto vacuum, and performed 10M transactions on other tables but this single transaction on non tx table not cleared by auto vacuum. how this transaction will be cleared ?

Comment: What is a nontransaction table?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I understand this question correctly if I assume that you are asking how a single deleted row in a table that does not receive any other data modifications will eventually get removed, thus preventing data corruption due to transaction ID wraparound.

PostgreSQL keeps track of the oldest transaction ID used in a non-frozen row of a table in the `relfrozenxid` column of `pg_class`. If that value is more than `autovacuum_freeze_max_age` transactions old (by default, 400 million), an anti-wraparound autovacuum run will be started that will insist on visiting all pages that are not all-frozen. That will get rid of the deleted row.